# How place overlay imageview on two layouts?

Tags: android, android-layout

I want to build the following screen which contains app logo, success/failure icon image, information message and ok button.

[image]

Here this the code. I am using linear layout to achieve this.

```
<LinearLayout
android:id="@+id/statusLinearLayout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:gravity="center"
android:background="@android:color/white"
android:weightSum="2"
android:orientation="vertical"
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/statusTopRelativeLayout"
    android:background="@android:color/holo_blue_bright"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_weight="1">
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/client_logo"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:contentDescription="@string/no_image_description"
        android:src="@drawable/client_logo"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"/>
</RelativeLayout>
<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/statusBottomRelativeLayout"
    android:background="@android:color/holo_blue_light"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1">
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/statusText"           
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
        android:text="@string/statusText"
        android:textSize="50sp"/>
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnOk"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/statusText"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="50dp"            
        android:clickable="true"
        android:focusable="true"
        android:onClick="goToHomeScreen"
        android:paddingBottom="15dp"
        android:paddingTop="15dp"
        android:text="@string/ok"
        android:textColor="#ffffff"
        android:textSize="40sp"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

How to place success/failure icon image on top of the two layouts?

Comment: Add the 2 layouts inside a Linear (vertical) layout. Then add this Linear layout inside a RelativeLayout along with the image.. Then place the Linear layout and the image on the center of the RelativeLayout. The order you place the items in the RelativeLayout matters on which item will be on top of the other (like z-axis).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">


    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/nilu"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:paddingBottom="30dp">


            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="NILU" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="NILU" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="NILU" />


        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/nilu2"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_below="@id/nilu"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@color/colorAccent"
            android:orientation="vertical">


            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="NILU" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="NILU" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="NILU" />

        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>


    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round" />


    </RelativeLayout>


</RelativeLayout>
```

**OUTPUT**

[image]

Comment: thanks, @Nilesh Rathod with minor changes to your solution I am done my changes.

Answer (score 2):

You can use constraint to make it easy

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

    <android.support.constraint.Guideline
        android:id="@+id/center"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.5"/>

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/center"
        android:background="#ffffff"/>

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@id/center"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        android:background="#00ffff"/>

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:background="#ff8801"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@id/center"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@id/center"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent" />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Output:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Parent RelativeLayout

- add child LinearLayout as fillParent and assign weightsum 2. add two
  layouts with 1 weight each. (add individual implementation for each
  layout according to your requirements.)
- add second child in relative
  layout as imageview/button for that good sign and set it center in
  parent.

This will fix your problem